# How to pause setInterval for the image elements inside a React Carousel Component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a Image Carousel Component in react which accepts images from a file upload utility. It has navigational controls, left arrow, right arrow and slick dots at the centre-bottom of the carousel. Also, when you click on an image in an carousel, it should open in a Modal. These requirements are working perfectly fine.

I have one more requirement to show the carousel images one by one automatically after a certain interval. I used setInterval() for this, inside useEffect() hook, the images inside the Carousel are changing. But the issue is: when I click on the image in the carousel, it opens up in a modal, and that also changes, like the images in the Carousel component.

So, I was thinking if there is any way to pause the setInterval() when the image is clicked and shown in a Modal? and again resume the setInterval() when the Modal is closed?

Second issue: How to add animation to the slides of the carousel like slide in or slide out?

**IMAGE COMPONENT**

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import Overlay from "../Overlay";
import "./Image.scss";

const Image = ({ imageSrc }) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleShowDialog = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <img
        className="original-image"
        src={imageSrc}
        onClick={handleShowDialog}
        alt="carousel"
      />
      {isModalOpen && (
        <Overlay closeOverlay={handleShowDialog}>
          <img className="modal-image" src={imageSrc} alt="carousel" />
        </Overlay>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Image;
```

**IMAGE CAROUSEL COMPONENT**

```
import "./Carousel.scss";
import Image from "../Image";
import CarouselControls from "./CarouselControls";

const ImageCarousel = ({ imageUrls }) => {
  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState(0);
  const [activeArrow, setActiveArrow] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPosition(0);
    const interval = setInterval(changeSlide, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [imageUrls]);

  const changeSlide = () => {
    const lastIndex = imageUrls.length - 1;
    setCurrentPosition(currentPosition => {
      return currentPosition === lastIndex ? 0 : currentPosition + 1;
    });
  };

  const goToPreviousSlide = () => {
    setActiveArrow("left");
    const newPosition =
      currentPosition === 0 ? imageUrls.length - 1 : currentPosition - 1;
    setCurrentPosition(newPosition);
  };

  const goToNextSlide = () => {
    setActiveArrow("right");
    const newPosition =
      currentPosition === imageUrls.length - 1 ? 0 : currentPosition + 1;
    setCurrentPosition(newPosition);
  };

  const goToParticularSlide = position => {
    setCurrentPosition(position);
  };

  return (
    <div className="image-carousel">
      <header className="carousel-header"> Image Carousel Component</header>
      {imageUrls && imageUrls.length > 0 && (
        <div className="carousel-container">
          <Image imageSrc={imageUrls[currentPosition]} />
          <CarouselControls
            imageUrls={imageUrls}
            activeArrow={activeArrow}
            currentPosition={currentPosition}
            goToNextSlide={goToNextSlide}
            goToParticularSlide={goToParticularSlide}
            goToPreviousSlide={goToPreviousSlide}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageCarousel;
```

My codesandbox.io link for the entire project : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-carousel-copy-sju4v

Comment: For your first issue, it should be possible to just use `clearInterval(handle)`, where `handle` is a variable to which you assigned the output of `setInterval` when you called it (like: `let handle = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);` ).  - - - - See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: I am using the same logic inside my useEffect() to stop the interval. I was wondering if we have any way to pause the setInterval timer, for sometime. Like, if I hover over the image in a carousel, the setInterval() timer should be paused, if I remove my mouse from there, again the timer should be resumed.

Comment: No, once it's set, it just continues until cleared. But you can call `clearInterval` on `mouseenter` (or `mouseover`), then call `setInterval` again with the same handle on `mouseleave` (or `mouseout`), which should be practically the same as your proposed `pause` and `resume` methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store your `setInterval` in a variable and use it to stop the loop like this:

```
let si = setInterval(changeSlide, 2000);

function stopInterval() {
  cancelInterval(si);
}
```

2. There are multiple ways to "slide" an element, here is an example:

```css
#container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#your_image {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* note: `infinite` just for demo. */
  animation: slide 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyFrames slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-150%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(150%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="your_image">
    image here
  </div>
</div>
```